# How to detect inside CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour if RecyclerView's item has been scrolled for 50%?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"          
        app:layout_behavior="com.github.an.CustomBehaviour">

        //Other views

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside `CustomBehaviour`'s `onNestedScroll(...)` I want to do some things if first `RecyclerView`'s element has been scrolled for 50%(or partially):

```
public class CustomBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<AppBarLayout> {

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final AppBarLayout appbar, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {

        if(first element scrolled partially) {
            do something
        }

    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?